# How to use route params in same component in React (react-router-dom v6)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How do I pass the **id** from `/profile/:id` to the function `generateProfile(findProfile(id))`

Below is my code

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from './Profile';
import '../assets/styles/App.css';
import seedProfiles from '../seedProfiles';
import generateProfile from '../helpers/profileHelper';

function App() {  
  const findProfile = id => seedProfiles.find(profile => profile.id === id);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route exact="true" path="/" element={<h1>PROFILES</h1>} />
      <Route 
         exact="true" 
         path="/profile/:id" 
         element={<Profile profile={generateProfile(findProfile(???))} />} 
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks

Comment: try using  let { id } = useParams(); inside the Profile component

Comment: i tried but doesn't work in same App component.

Comment: is it possible to pass Profile  a function const generateProfile = id => generateProfile(findProfile(id)) and useMemo or useEffect to set the profile since  useParams needs the context

Comment: Its generally not a good idea to use window.location  or  window.location.href since React wont sync with those changes

Comment: This is what `useParams` hook is for. But why do you need to do this? Why don't you move this logic to `Profile` instead of passing it as props and use the hook in that component to get the dynamic param?

Comment: Thanks everybody........i moved it to the other component

Answer (score 0):

Route path parameters are only accessible via the `useParams` hook. If you need to access the route path parameters *prior* to rendering the routed component then you'd need to create a wrapping component that can "sniff" the parameters and apply any logic.

Example:

```js
const ProfileWrapper = ({ getProfile }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  return <Profile profile={getProfile(id)} />
};

function App() {  
  const getProfile = id => generateProfile(
    seedProfiles.find(profile => profile.id === id)
  );

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<h1>PROFILES</h1>} />
      <Route 
         path="/profile/:id" 
         element={<ProfileWrapper profile={getProfile} />} 
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

However, it's more common to move this logic into the component being rendered since there are not really any parental dependencies.

Example:

```js
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from './Profile';
import '../assets/styles/App.css';
import seedProfiles from '../seedProfiles';
import generateProfile from '../helpers/profileHelper';

const Profile = () => { 
  const { id } = useParams();

  const profile = generateProfile(seedProfiles.find(profile => profile.id === id));

  return ...;
}
```

```js
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from './Profile';
import '../assets/styles/App.css';

function App() {  
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<h1>PROFILES</h1>} />
      <Route path="/profile/:id" element={<Profile />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```